# SOLR open search on multiple tables

Tags: apache, solr

Say I have `authors`,`publishers`,`books` where `authors` or `publishers` may have zero books stored in my DB

how do I index (i.e. config data-congig.xml / schema.xml) my tables so my users can freely type a book title, a publisher or author name and find some results?

Answer (score -1):

1.Make author, publisher, book_title fields in schema and define these filed in qf( query fields) in solr query.
2.You can make a single filed having name of author concatenated with publisher and book title for each book. Make documents book wise. Match searched string in that field it will return all possible results.